# How do I find a file that I am trying to unzip using ZipArchive?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, unzip, php-ziparchive, dispatch-async

ZipArchive is not able to locate the file that I am trying to unzip. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to do all of this in dispatch_async, is that my problem?

I end up with "Could not find zip file." in my log. And when I check look for the directory that should have been created in my app data file, it is nowhere to be found. How ever the zip file is there.

Here is a link to a [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/08/13/unzipping-files-using-zip-archive/) that closely resembles what I am trying to do. I have also added the libraries needed.

**Code Edited** Per Request to include error handling:

```
    NSLog(@"Got the data!");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

    //Save the data
    NSLog(@"Saving");
    NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TKAPlacesImages.zip"];
    dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [urlData writeToFile:dataPath options:0 error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {

        if (![defaults objectForKey:@"places images path"]) {
            [defaults setObject:path forKey:@"places images path"];

            [defaults synchronize];
        }

        ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
        if( [za UnzipOpenFile:dataPath] )
        {
            BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:path overWrite: YES];
            if (NO == ret){} [za UnzipCloseFile];

            NSLog(@"Successful unzip of: %@",@"/Library/Caches/TKAPlacesImages.zip");
        }
        else
        {



            NSLog(@"Could not find zip file.");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving file %@",error);
    }
```

**PHP Code Added**

```
function zip_image_files($images) {

    // Prepare File
    $file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    $imagesCount = count($images);
    $imagesString = '';

    for($i=0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++)
    {
        // Stuff with content
        $imagesString = ".." . $images[$i];

        if(file_exists($imagesString))
        {
            $zip->addFile($imagesString);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $imagesString;
        }

    }//end for

    // Close and send to users
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file); 

}
//end function
```

**Edit**
My function returns a 19.2MB zip file. However in my app data file the zip file is 0 bytes.

Comment: How far does this code get? What happens?

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my question for you.

Comment: You are calling `writeToFile:` without error checking. Add the error checking! It returns a BOOL that tells you whether the write succeeded or not.

Comment: Also (irrelevant to this question, but it will bite you later) you are assuming a hard-coded path `@"/Library/Caches/TKAPlacesImages"` when you store the path in your user defaults. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that either (1) `urlData` is nil and so nothing is being written because there is nothing to write or (2) `urlData` is not zipped data and to unzip it is failing. Chances are that the first one is the actual issue, since you say you don't see any written file.

Comment: I added some more information that might be helpful.